# php mysql filter option on table results

Tags: php, mysql

currently, I have a rendered table with the corresponding search results. My question, How can I add a filter option that will filter upon a specific field but only if the table renders more than 25 results?

```
    <?php

$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search']; 

if(strlen($search)<=1)
echo "Search term too short";
else{
mysql_connect("*******.lininteractive.com","**********","********");
mysql_select_db("admin_diceydining");

$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

$x = "";
$construct = "";  

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
$x++;
if($x==1)
$construct .="Name LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct .="AND PCITY LIKE '%$search_each%'";

}

$constructs ="SELECT * FROM broadway WHERE $construct";
$run = mysql_query($constructs);

$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

if ($foundnum==0)
echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search</b>.</br></br>1. 
Try more general words. for example: If you want to search 'how to create a website'
then use general keyword like 'create' 'website'</br>2. Try different words with similar
 meaning</br>3. Please check your spelling";
else
{ 


$per_page = 25;
$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start']: '';
$max_pages = ceil($foundnum / $per_page);
if(!$start)
$start=0; 
$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM broadway WHERE $construct LIMIT $start, $per_page");

    echo "<table data-toggle='table' data-sort-name='name' data-sort-order='desc'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th data-sortable='true'>Date</th><th data-field='Name' data-align='left' data-sortable='true'>Name</th><th>City</th><th>Description</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";

    while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery)) {
    // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$runrows['Name']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$runrows['PCITY']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$runrows['TYPE']}</td>";
    echo '<td><a href="results2.php?nameID=' .$runrows['ID'].'">' .substr($runrows['DESCR'], 0, 35) .'</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
    // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])

    }

    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Just hid database info

Answer (score 0):

You may execute a query for counting result like

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM broadway WHERE $construct;

and after you know the row number of result, you can chose what to do.